# Al usar TableLayoutPanels se traba Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Cuando uso TableLayoutPanels Visual Studio empieza a trabarse cada que hago un movimiento de controles en ese form y se recupera como 20 segundos después.
¿Es común que pase esto?
¿Se puede arreglar?
Utilizo la versión Community 2017.

Comment: memoria, procesador y tipo de disco duro de tu pc? tienes instalados muchas extensiones en Visual Studio? cuantos proyectos tiene tu solución? te pasa incluso en proyectos nuevos con una sola ventana? has verificado si no es cosa del antivirus?

Comment: Tiene 4 GB de RAM y Core I5 6600T, pero no los explota. La RAM no llega ni al 60%. No tengo muchas extensiones. Tengo dos proyectos en la solución. Me ha pasado con otros proyectos. Sólo me pasa cuando pongo TableLayoutPanels en el form, nada más. ¿Es posible que el antivirus haga algo así?

Comment: Es normal, todo lo que es interfaces gráficas en Visual Studio va lento, te recomiendo ya que hayas ordenado tus paneles, moverle a los componentes desde el "Document Outline", eso evitará que le estés picando a la ventana y intente renderear nuevamente. https://imgur.com/a/o2ImneD

Comment: Lo intentaré. Muchas gracias.